# What is the subjectDescriptor in the Personal Access Token API for Azure

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to write a script to automate some aspects of our Azure DevOps environment but I am struggling to be able to return the PAT's for a specific user to be able to authorize them to execute API calls. Would someone be able to give me an example of what the subjectDescriptor is and where I can find it? I have read through [microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/personal%20access%20tokens/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) but it is not very helpful in this and I could not find an example of what value should be passed into subjectDescriptor for the GET request.

Basically what I am trying to do is write a powershell script that a user has to authenticate into and then the script will pull their PAT's and execute API calls based on the access that the user has.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below api could help you achieve what you want? Don’t hesitate to let us know if you still has any puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What the subjectDescriptor is and where I can find it?

In the security of Azure Devops, `subjectDescriptor` is user's `SID`. It used as identification when operating some security control. This parameter can **uniquely identify** the same graph subject across both Accounts and Organizations.

To get it, just use the following [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

From its response body, you can get the `descriptor` value of corresponding user.

[image]

Next, you can pass the corresponding descriptor value into the [list PAT token API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/personal%20access%20tokens/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

---

In addition, you can also due to this [blog](https://blog.devopsabcs.com/index.php/2019/06/24/one-project-to-rule-them-all-3/) which written by our engineer.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#storage-keys Here it is mentioned that we should not persist descriptor.  If we want to find the user details later, without persisting what should we do? About storage keys, 1. it is mentioned they are not unique 2. Everytime we have to make 2 calls to get storage key from descriptor and vice versa