# Finding Descriptor Identifier using devops REST API

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to make a post to the `dev.azure.com{organization}/_apis/accesscontrolentries/{namespaceId}?api-version=5.1`.

I need help on obtaining the descriptor that starts with `S-1-9`.

```
{ "token": "", "merge": true, "accessControlEntries": [ { "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-**********-**********-**********-**********-**********-*-**********-**********-**********-**********", "allow": 128, "deny": 0 } ] }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obtaining the descriptor that starts with S-1-9.

There’s no directly rest api to get this descriptor which start with S-1-9. You need to use the follow api get the `user descriptor(SID)` firstly:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

I have one answer about how to obtain it from response body, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074586/11508165) for more details.

Now the descriptor we get is based on `base64`. To achieve what you want, just decode this SID.

Here has a blog which written by our Azure Identity Team engineer: [C# Decode script](https://blog.devopsabcs.com/index.php/2019/06/24/one-project-to-rule-them-all-3/). Just located to the corresponding part to achieve this decode script:

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
        {
            var lengthMod4 = base64EncodedData.Length % 4;
            if (lengthMod4 != 0)
            {
                //fix Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string
                base64EncodedData += new string('=', 4 - lengthMod4);
            }
            var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
        }

public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }
```

Comment: @Ryguy444222 Great! You can [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/541930).